# How to create a validator for special characters in DJANGO?

Tags: python, django

my site is live but it has a problem. Whenever someone signs up with a special character in their username then the server gives an error (for the entire site) as the slug cannot display special characters such as @,-,| but django user model lets users sign up with special characters. Is there a way I can throw in a validator error in my signup form.

below is my forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

    captcha = CaptchaField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length= 15, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not data.islower():
           raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames should be in lowercase")
         return data

    class Meta:
       model = User
       help_texts = {
        'username': 'Required. Please only use lower-case alphabets and 
        numbers.',
          }
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

views.py

class SignUpFormView(View):
     form_class = SignUpForm
     template_name = 'home/signup.html'

```
#if there is no sign up yet
def get(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

#if going to sig up
def post(self,request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        #it takes information but does save it
        user = form.save(commit = False)
        #cleaned normalized data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        #returns if it is all correct

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("userprofile:newprofile")

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean_username(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if not data.islower():
           raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames should be in lowercase")
        if '@' in data or '-' in data or '|' in data:
           raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames should not have special characters.")
        return data
```

you can use this

Answer (score 3):

If understand you want to validate that just digits or letters are accepted for sign in right?

you can do it like that:

```
def validate_digits_letters(word):
    for char in word:
        if not char.isdigit() and not char.isalpha():
            return False
    return True


def clean_username(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['username']
    if not data.islower():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames should be in lowercase")

    if not validate_digits_letters(data):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Usernames contains characters that are not numbers nor letters")

    return data
```